# Workbook was not recalculated when it was last saved

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I just encounter an issue when i want to edit link and change source one of my working excel files. It turns out that previous owner of the files didn't recalculated the source files. I already try several way to change the previous link location, like replacing, open the target file, but it's not worked.

The method to solve this is to actually open the original source which i don't have and creating dummy source would be a best way to solve this, but there is a restriction since this is my work PC.

Can anyone recommend solution for this? otherwise I need to update every formula manually and figures out which one need to be updated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this article helps: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/refresh-an-external-data-connection-in-excel-1524175f-777a-48fc-8fc7-c8514b984440

Comment: I tried this and it's not worked

Answer (score 0):

Open the workbook that is not recalculating formulas.

File, Options.

Click on the Formulas section, Left Side of the window.

Select Automatic for Workbook Calculation.

Close options and save the Workbook.

If you do not have the needed workbooks and obtaining them is not an option , then you will need to rebuild your workbook project from scratch.

Comment: the problem is that I don't have the source files anymore

Comment: Can you track down the owner?  Otherwise you need to write new source files. That could be quite a job.

Comment: no, like I mentioned, i dont have the files anymore. I dont have access to mimic the location of previous files. so I can use this as dummy open and change it with new files. But that's not the cases